# boto3 support for role_arn

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I want to insert data from AWS Lambda to AWS DynamoDB and upload a file from Lambda to AWS S3. Currently, I'm using Access Key and Secret Key to do this from boto3.

But, due to security issues, I had to change this approach to role-based approach. (i.e) To insert data in DDB or uploading a file to S3 I should use the provided role_ARN.

I had spent enough time in searching for a clue of doing this. If anybody knows please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain little about what permissions you need From question, You  need permissions from 1.   AWS lambda to access dynamobd and 2. Lambda to aws s3.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a role to a Lambda function which the AWS documents usually refer to as **LambdaExecution** role. Instead of using AWS credentials in your Lambda code, you can just assign a corresponding IAM role to your Lambda.

See: [Create the Execution Role (IAM Role)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-create-iam-role.html)
Do not create a new role as described in the link. Instead attach your pre-created role to your Lambda in the following step:

> In Attach Policy, choose AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole.

In your case,

> In Attach Policy, choose provided_role_ARN